# How to create separate frequency tables with multiple filters and export those new tables into my desktop?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create frequency tables for each domestic and international school with each degree (associate, bachelor, and graduate degrees). My goal is to make a table like these in R and export these tables on my desktop:

Domestic graduates – Associates degree (n = total amount of applicants with associate's degree)

| Institution | Count | % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NYU | 67 | 15 |
| Stanford | 89 | 12 |

International graduates – Associates degree (n = total amount of applicants with associate's degree)

| Institution | Count | % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Oxford | 65 | 10 |
| Cambridge | 99 | 9 |

The problem is that I am having trouble filtering the schools for each degree in separate tables (I need the tables like the ones above). Here is my code so far (I know it is wrong):

```
    {r}
df %>%
 filter(college_state_0== "Texas") %>%
 freq_table( college_name_0, college_first_degree_0) %>%
  arrange(desc(n))
```

Current Output:

| College Name | Degree | Count | % |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NYU | Bachelor of Science | 55 | 23 |
| Cornell | Associates | 32 | 22 |
| UCLA | Bachelor of Arts | 12 | 20 |

I appreciate everyone's help as I am new to this platform. If this is not clear, please leave a comment below.

Comment: Hi! Maybe you want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: How do you identify which are domestic and which international colleges?

Comment: It is easier if you provide a minimal reproducible example (you can use `dput(df)` where `df` is a subset of your dataset which enough information to reproduce your issue.  Also, it will be great if you show clearly your expected output (is it current output?)

Comment: @RobertoT the expected output is the goal shown (the first 2 tables).

Comment: @RicVillalba in my dataset, the variable college_country_0 is what defines US and other countries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply trying to do grouped summaries, where the two grouping variables are the School & the Degree

This code counts each degree type and college type, then takes the percent of the whole set.

```
  new_df<-df %>%
      group_by(college_name_0, college_first_degree_0)%>%
      summarise(Count = n())%>%
      ungroup()%>%
      mutate(Percent = 100*Count/sum(Count))
```

If you need percents by state, add the state filtering in first.

```
new_df<-df %>%
      filter(college_state_0== "Texas") %>%
      group_by(college_name_0, college_first_degree_0)%>%
      summarise(Count = n())%>%
      ungroup()%>%
      mutate(Percent = 100*Count/sum(Count))
```

With the data ungrouped, you could effectively regroup by state and do the percent aggregation all in one giant table them extract what you need for each table

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and for the information provided! This has helped me learn more about R and coding format.

Comment: You are very welcome. This is considered "Tidy" R and there is a package and philosophy behind it that super simplifies manipulating data in R!